# systemd-networkd delete cached dhcp-assigned ip address

Tags: linux, systemd-networkd

Where are the IP addresses, assigned through systemd-networkd DHCP, cached? I have changed my router and have a totally different setup, including preferred addresses for hosts. My host (my workstation) keeps asking for an extension on the lease of an IP address that is not the one preferred by the DHCP server. This makes a mess of my DNS. How can I force my host to start with a totally clean slate?

Comment: To flush the dns cache: `systemctl restart dns-clean.service`

Comment: Regrettably, it's not my dns cache that's the problem, but the cached dhcp address assignment, that is reused when re-booting.

Answer (score 1):

According to systemd's [source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/9d0798a/src/network/networkd-link.c#L474-L481), lease information is saved in `/run/systemd/netif/leases/<number>`.
But the problem is that the whole `/run` directory is `tmpfs` and thus should be deleted on reboot. Maybe it is cached somewhere though.

In my situation the problem was on a router, after updating static leases configuration in dd-wrt I didn't purge lease cache on the router itself.